# GridView not displaying

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ado.net, sqldatareader

This is pretty straightforward. I have a GridView and I set the data source in the codebehind, but the GridView doesn't display at all.

ASPX:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="scorecard.aspx.cs" Inherits="Scorecard" Title="Scorecard" %>

<form runat="server">
    <div style="background-color: maroon; height: 100%;" runat="server">
        <div style="background-color: white;">
            <img src="le log.jpg" />
        </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:GridView>
    </div>
</form>
```

CodeBehind:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class Scorecard : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var username = Request.Params["LOGON_USER"].ToString();
        var track = Request.Params["track"].ToString();

        var userKey = 0;
        var fullName = "";

        if (Request.Params["track"] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(username))
        {
            Response.Write("<p style=\"color: red;\">An error occurred. Try again.</p>");
        }
        else
        {
            var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/");

            if (config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["CompanyCollege"];

                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString.ConnectionString))
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT UserKey, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName FROM UserProfile WHERE Username = '{0}'", username), conn);
                        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Report_AssessmentTrackingByUser", conn);
                        cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd2.Parameters.Add("@UserKey", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int);
                        cmd2.Parameters["@UserKey"].Value = userKey;

                        conn.Open();

                        using (var reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                userKey = (int)reader.GetValue(0);
                                fullName = (string)reader.GetValue(1);
                            }
                        }

                        using (var reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            dt.Load(reader);
                            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<p style=\"color: red;\">An error occurred. Try again.</p>");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: Did you run the code through with the debugger and 1) make sure the code that binds the GV is reached and 2) make sure there's rows in the data table?

Comment: Can't debug. It's a live site and I have no project files to work with. Trust me, it's more aggravating to me than it is to anybody that might be able to answer this question. @mason

Comment: Well, then have the site write some debugging info. Append it to a label or have it email you. Do that until you've narrowed the issue down.

Comment: Since no error is being thrown, we can assume your databinding is occurring. Here's something you can do for testing purposes, add the attribute `EmptyDataText` Ex: `EmptyDataText="No data to bind."` to your Gridview, so that if there is no data it will still display the value of that. I'm guessing your reader has no rows.